# What does the & do in front of an argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, arguments

I'm doing some Ruby Koan exercises. Since i'm quite a newbie, so some code doesn't seem to make sense for me. For example, the `&` in front of an argument

```
def method_with_explicit_block(&block)
    block.call(10)
end

def test_methods_can_take_an_explicit_block_argument
assert_equal 20, method_with_explicit_block { |n| n * 2 }

add_one = lambda { |n| n + 1 }
assert_equal 11, method_with_explicit_block(&add_one)
end
```

Why there's a `&` before `block` and `add_one`? To make them global variables or refer them to the previous variable?

Thank you!

Comment: You're basically passing in a block of code as an argument, and when using `call` within your method, you're calling on that block and using it there. So you can see `method_with_explicit_block( {|n| n * 2 } )`, you're invoking this method, and passing that block argument. Inside method `method_with_explicit_block`, you can see its being called `block.call(10)`, and an argument of `10` is being passed to the block. Inside the block ` {|n| n * 2}`, `n = 10` in this case. And since that block call is the last line in that method, the result of the block will return.

Answer (score 6):

In front of a *parameter in method definition*, the unary prefix ampersand `&` sigil means: package the block passed to this method as a proper `Proc` object.

In front of an *argument in method call*, the unary prefix ampersand `&` operator means: convert the object passed as an argument to a `Proc` by sending it the message `to_proc` (unless it already is a `Proc`) and "unroll" it into a block, i.e. treat the `Proc` as if it had been passed directly as a block instead.

Answer (score 2):

Example in case of procs

```
multiples_of_3 = Proc.new do |n|
  n%3 == 0
end

(1..100).to_a.select(&multiples_of_3)
```

The "&" here is used to convert proc into block.

Another Example
 It’s how you can pass a reference to the block (instead of a local variable) to a method. Ruby allows you to pass any object to a method as if it were a block. The method will try to use the passed in object if it’s already a block but if it’s not a block it will call to_proc on it in an attempt to convert it to a block.

Also note that the block part (without the ampersand) is just a name for the reference, you can use whatever name you like if it makes more sense to you.

```
def my_method(&block)
  puts block
  block.call
end

my_method { puts "Hello!" }
#<Proc:0x0000010124e5a8@tmp/example.rb:6>
Hello!
```

As you can see in the example above, the block variable inside my_method is a reference to the block and it can be executed with the call method. call on the block is the same as using yield, some people like to use block.call instead of yield for better readability.